# Python to EXE - Space Invaders Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I have no clue on how to compile multiple python files into an exe. I am making a space-invaders game. The main.py is the main-menu which imports the game-mode modules: single player multiplayer etc via the command (which is in the code of main.py and import subprocess is at the top)

```
subprocess.call("whatever game mode", shell=True)
```

there are also dependancies on 2 resource folder named "Resource" and "Yasin" from which the various modules call images from.

I am having trouble with combining all the resource folders and modules into one executable. All the examples I see are with simple python code that have only 1 python file where no images are used
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ5ZL.png

Answer (score 0):

Most python-to-exe type programs will automatically include any imports when creating the exe file. As long as main.py imports the others, it should work fine. Try following [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) tutorial, with 'main.py' instead of 'hello.py', of course.